# How can I properly setup a Loading screen in Vue3 and Vite?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuex, vite

I want to setup a Loading screen on App loading. I am currently using a Loading component and setting up its time interval to 2 seconds. However, that is not the proper way to set up a Loading screen. What is the best way to handle the loading state for the entire app?

I have directly used the Loading component in the router-view of the `App.vue`, so I do not have to use the Loading component in each and every component of the App.

The following is my `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-app class="container">
    <v-app-bar color="green" class="app-bar">
      <v-toolbar-title class="ml-0 pl-4">
        <span class="hidden-sm-and-down">{{ appName }}</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-btn rounded depressed dark large @click="gotoHome()">
        <h3>Dashboard</h3>
        <v-icon class="px-2">mdi-ballot</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn rounded depressed dark large @click="dialog = !dialog">
        <h3>Markets</h3>
        <v-icon class="px-2">mdi-apps</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn rounded depressed dark large @click="gotoSettings()">
        <h3>Settings</h3>
        <v-icon class="px-2">settings</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn rounded depressed dark large @click="gotoVerus()">
        <h3>Verus</h3>
        <v-icon class="px-2">mdi-apps</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" fullscreen hide-overlay transition="dialog-bottom-transition">
      <v-card>
        <v-toolbar>
          <v-btn dark @click="dialog = false">
            <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-toolbar-title>Markets</v-toolbar-title>
          <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
          <v-toolbar-items>
            <v-btn dark text @click="dialog = false">back</v-btn>
          </v-toolbar-items>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-list three-line subheader>
          <v-subheader>Go to markets</v-subheader>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>Informational Section</v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle>Please wait for the available market links to load</v-list-item-subtitle>
              <AppMarkets v-on:gotoMarket="gotoMarket" :key="componentKey" />
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
    <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        location="left"
        temporary
      >
        <v-list
          :items="items"
        ></v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
      <Loading v-if="loading"></Loading>
      <router-view v-else>
      </router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>


<script>
import AppMarkets from './views/AppMarkets.vue'
import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue'
import Loading from './Loading.vue'


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    AppMarkets,
    Loading
},
  props: {
    source: String
  },
  setup() {
    const loading = ref(true);
    onMounted(() => {
      // For demonstration purposes, setting loading to true for 2 seconds.
      setTimeout(() => {
        loading.value = false;
      }, 2000);
  });
    return {
      loading,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    gotoHome() {
      this.$router.push('/')
    },
    gotoSettings() {
      this.$router.push('/settings')
    },
    gotoVerus() {
      this.$router.push('/verus')
    },
    gotoMarket: function(base, rel) {
      console.log("Going to new market..." + base + "/")// + rel)
      console.log(this.componentKey)
      this.componentKey += 1
      this.dialog = !this.dialog
      window.location.href='/traderview/'+base+'/'+rel;
    },
    doAction: function(command) {
      window.location.href = "/" + command.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "");
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    appName: 'OrderBook Live',
    base: '',  
    componentKey: ref(0),
    dialog: ref(false),
    drawer: ref(false),
  }),
  
  
}
</script>
```

Comment: loading screens are usually tied to async operations/network requests, i.e. set the loading screen = true before the operation, then false after.  the question is a bit vague and it's not clear what your actual use case is to provide a definite answer.

Comment: Updated my question hope now I would get some help

Comment: You didn't really add any important information to the question.  What loading tasks are you talking about?  There's no async tasks that I see in your code.  You say you have timeout right now to show the loading screen for 2 seconds.  What in those 2 seconds is your app "loading" (files, network requests, something else) that you need the loading screen for?  Be specific.  If you can't name anything specific, then maybe you don't actually need a loading screen.

Comment: On components loading simple

Comment: From everything communicated so far it seems like you're looking for a reason to use a loading screen without having an actual need.

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3, the lifecycle of a component goes through several stages, from creation to destruction. The key lifecycle hooks are:

In your case you can set loading to true **beforemount** and to false when component fully loaded in **mounted**
or if there is any data request you can use it inside that request as well

**BeforeCreate**: This is triggered before the instance is created. At this point, the data observation, events, and watchers are set up, but the template compilation has not occurred.

**Created**: The created hook is called after the instance is created. At this stage, the instance has been initialized, and you can access data, methods, and events.

**BeforeMount**: This is called right before the mounting begins. The virtual DOM is created, and the component is about to be rendered.

**Mounted**: This hook is called after the component has been mounted to the DOM, meaning it is fully loaded and visible. It is often used for making API calls or manipulating the DOM after the component has been rendered.

**BeforeUpdate**: This hook is called when data changes and the component is about to re-render. You can perform actions before the update.

**Updated**: Called after a data change causes the component to re-render. At this point, the DOM has been updated to reflect the latest changes.

**BeforeUnmount**: Called right before a component is unmounted. You can perform cleanup operations here.

**Unmounted**: Called after a component is unmounted and destroyed. It's used for cleanup and releasing resources.